# Is there a way to run donet sonnarscanner inside docker container in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to do some SonarCloud code analyses on Jenkins with a donet docker container that is already built by my organization. However, I have to install the sonnarscanner tool on top of it, but I am getting permission denials when running the tool.
This is what I've tried so far:

```
stage("Pull dotnet image") {
        dotnetCoreImage = dockerImage("dotnet2.0")
    }

    dotnetCoreImage.inside() {
            stage("Start sonar scanner") {
                sh "dotnet tool install --tool-path /tmp/.donet/tools dotnet-sonarscanner; \
                    chmod 777 /tmp/.donet/tools/ -R;
                    export PATH=/tmp/.donet/tools; \
                    dotnet sonarscanner begin \
                            /d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
                            /v:'1.0' \
                     /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths='src/test/coverage/*.opencover.xml'\
                            /d:sonar.branch.name=${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
```

But I get the following errors:

`16:00:46.527  16:00:46.527  WARNING: Error occurred when installing the loader targets to '/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore/SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets'. 'Access to the path '/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore' is denied.'`

So my question is if there is a way to run inside the docker image with more permissions such as root.

(Cannot do sudo since it is not installed in the docker image)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution?